# Typescript: property based on another property

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have a situation of nested types and what I would like to achieve is to have a specified property based on another property's value.

In the HTML I cycle the response of an API and, based on the type value received, I would like to have a different option value.

For example: if I receive a response where type is 'articles' I would like to have OptionArticles as ChatOptions.

Is there a solution for this?

This is the code:

```
export interface ChatMessage {
    status: string;
    query: string;
    step: string;
    richResponse: boolean;
    payload: ChatPayload;
    sessionId?: number;
}

interface ChatPayload {
    type: ChatTypes;
    options: ChatOptions;
    confidence?: number;
    gotAllParams?: boolean;
}

type ChatTypes = 'text' | 'date' | 'articles' | 'params';

type ChatOptions = OptionText | OptionArticles | OptionParams;

interface OptionText {
    type: 'text' | 'date';
    text: string[];
}

interface OptionArticles {
    type: 'articles';
    prefilled: Values[];
    possible: Values[];
}

interface OptionParams {
    type: 'params';
    params: FineParams;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to enforce that the type in `chatPayload` is the same as the type in `chatPayload.options`.

ChatPayload can take as a type parameter the "type" from the API:

```
interface ChatPayload<Type extends ChatTypes> {
    type: Type;
    options: Type extends "articles" ? OptionArticles : Type extends "params" ? OptionParams : OptionText ;
    confidence?: number;
    gotAllParams?: boolean;
}
```

And you can switch the type depending on the value of the field in the API response:

```
// the response you get from the API; you don't know the type yet
const apiResponse: any = {}

if (apiResponse.type === "text" || apiResponse.type === "date") {
    doSomething(apiResponse as ChatPayload<"text" | "date">)
} else if (apiResponse.type === "articles") {
    doSomething(apiResponse as ChatPayload<"articles">)
} else if (apiResponse.type === "params") {
    doSomething(apiResponse as ChatPayload<"params">)
} else {
    throw new Error("unexpected type")
}
```

The casting is a little ugly, but you will have to use a cast in order to get an untyped API response into one of your own types.

For further safety, you can use a JSON validator to make sure that the response you're getting from the API conforms to what you expect.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=47&ssc=2&pln=36&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQAtMYBZYAZwswHNgAeAFQE8w9RUkATCg4mFmwoA%20OAG8AUHGlwKMEgFcKALlkwoyGgG4pMgI4K0zVXI1Jtu6XOBgT6zTplwN2QgCVKkJBWCqARhAQADbAmEiOMmCYzEEQmFyqRCQACtGx8UyswMIRVpQUCBBIAJJcAPyqSAoAtn5oOgC%20EhLIqBg4eEkwqTFxXJlscBzA3LxdgpSikk4wWaoTuXAQYDCF3vNZQyCcPHAARJiwCNghFHtwZXAA8itrAIJHJ5RwG4PDo-tRUJjVZxfXtyKqW%20vxeANWRUYHDgi2wRXQCC4I1wFTgVVq9UscBoEBgdyCQWBPwoqICwVC4QkTQks0G4yyvAAvHAAOSobYsuAAH1ZXBIwE5PJZh1WTwogtZX2JLJ0LRQaCwuHBayh23EWNpvlZ7JgEpZfNQMo1HDsZhoAG0ALqNZqtBUdZVFB6i07qmZzVki46nI1OMBQYAIgnABJwMLMK2LSBUBB%20EKqcORqm2%20XtJU3CFIImg6YyTWqFlS36%20yKHYkJpDMG3NAD0NbgMEIeADFC8PjgzAgCmxwHg6CgEGqDabcDuyWKWg7XbgXCKbLgAGskBAAO7DvCaju9iRw7zwTBgBAeVtFHwV5hwZliakIdBwAAUB6PnlPwAAdJvGV-9jrzlyeU%20x5tu%20n7fnsBrAHsACUboyLOADKg69oQmiPoeQGvmGYz8D06T9Hsv7cvsEF7MIUFUkMQTtreD6AS%203ggZsX7MgcjynNBsHSAhSGNqhdEngxWF8CkaR9PQrEupQpHkQ0lHUXeaHPgJPgfkxYFFmcMG5lxECIdUyF8eh9Htpg2Eib0GR7Bp0kUcAVF4Npw4DmuSDAGuACiUADlA957AorngMA2CoFwDZZNBVJAA)

Comment: Thank you @vroomfondel, this works perfectly. 
The only correction you should do to your code is that, on the switch, it should be "as ChatMessage" not ChatPayload. For the rest is perfect! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a setter for a field in your class. This method will be called everytime a value is set for this field.

In the setter you can change the value of other field as well.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/typescript-accessor/

Note: You may have to class instead of interface for the ChatPayload